# I am not able to add members in a cohort externally in moodle

Tags: php, drupal, moodle

I am trying to add members in a cohort but whenever i call the function this is the response i get.I am using drupal rest to make the api call.

```
{
    "exception": "dml_write_exception",
    "errorcode": "dmlwriteexception",
    "message": "Error writing to database",
    "debuginfo": "Column 'role_id' cannot be null\nINSERT INTO mdl_cohort_members (cohortid,userid,timeadded,role_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)\n[array (\n  0 => '3',\n  1 => '52367',\n  2 => 1460546128,\n  3 => NULL,\n)]"
}
```

Can somebody direct me towards the solution.

```
{
   $fname = 'core_cohort_add_cohort_members';                    
  /// Paramètres
  $member = new stdClass();
  $member->cohorttype['type']='id';
  $member->cohorttype['value']='3';
  $member->usertype['type']='id';
  $member->usertype['value']='5';

  $members = array($member);
  $par = array('members' => $members);
  $rest_format = 'json';

  $Serve_Url = 'http://dev-lms.teletaleem.net' . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . '7882bb500bcefcd8778de64b8e79a19a' .'&wsfunction='. $fname;
  require_once('curl.inc');
   $Rest_format = ($rest_format == 'json') ? '&moodlewsrestformat=' . $rest_format : '';
  $curl = new curl;
  //if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
  $rep = $curl->post($Serve_Url.$Rest_format, $par);
  dpm($rep);
}
```